# UI-Router doesn't load templates from $templateCache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wan't to create nested states for tab navigation. And I also need to have all my tabs in the same file.

So I desided to use `$templateCache` for it.

Here is my `ui-router`'s configs:

```
$stateProvider
.state('books', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/books',
  controller: 'BooksCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books.html'
})
.state('books.best', {
  url: '/best',
  templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
    console.log('getting bookBestTab.html'); // is logged
    return $templateCache.get('bookBestTab.html');
  }
})
.state('books.new', {
  url: '/new',
  templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
    console.log('getting bookNewTab.html'); // is logged
    return $templateCache.get('bookNewTab.html');
  }
});
```

Here is my `contents/books.html` file:

```
<div>
    <!--Some common stuff-->
</div>
<div ui-view></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="bookBestTab.html">
    <!-- best books table -->
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="bookNewTab.html">
    <!-- new books table -->
</script>
```

When I go to the `books/best` or `books/new` URL, `contents/books.html` template is loaded and shown, but neither `bookBestTab.html` nor `bookNewTab.html` was ever shown.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Perhaps because the two templates you are trying to load are within the books.html template they don't get inserted into the $templateCache in time for the request to succeed.  Perhaps load them in your index.html file?

Comment: @ewahner could be, but do you know is there a way to keep the templates within the `books.html`?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to.  By either putting them in a file that gets loaded when the application boots up or by putting them in a different file location and then having $templateCache load them from that location makes alot more sense to me.  Keep your views modular.  Don't stuff views in your views that is what UI-Router is for and the ui-view tag.